# Python much slower on server than locally

Tags: python, optimization

I'm running a service where user motion data is sent to my python server in chunks, the chunks are analyzed for recognized patterns, and results are sent back to the user.

The problem is that locally, the data processing takes about .08 seconds per chunk but when I time the processing on the server it takes .75 seconds, which is too slow.

My local machine is comparable in specs to my remote AWS instance so I am confident that it's not a matter of machine capabilities.

The structure of the pipeline is as follows:

```
package
---packet_dispatcher.py  # packets received and sent to/received from pipeline queue
---queue.py  # queue object receives new packets for a given user and preps them for pipeline
---pipeline.py  # collection of pipeline stages which perform analysis
```

I thought initially that my local pycharm IDE could be doing something fancy with imports to make things faster so I wasn't importing the same modules every time but I tried running the process locally in my terminal and it was just as fast.

Why is this happening? I understand I have probably left critical information out so please let me know what else is needed to assess the situation and I will edit my question.

Comment: First use cProfile to find out where the time is being spent.

Comment: Just to check - you are excluding the network time?

Comment: yes the time is started when a packet is received and stopped right before it is sent